# Why does a user have the ability to add a GitHub link in any community?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, github

I was wondering why users have the ability to add GitHub links to their profile on Stack Exchange sites not related to programming at all.

Comment: A note that though the majority of content put on GitHub is Programming related, it doesn't have to be. GitHub is a version control service and what you version control doesn't need to be a program. It could be a table top game's rule you're designing that's written Markdown, or a much of scripts for your Linux deployments, for example. GitHub could easily be used for far more projects that the sites in the community explicitly aimed at programming.

Comment: I've seen books written in markup published on GitHub, so what?!?

Comment: Even if GitHub were only for programming-related content and someone wants to have a GitHub link in their [Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) profile, why stop them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because all Stack Exchange Sites use the same Q/A engine based and follows the Stack Overflow mother ship.

There are a few settings / features that can be tweaked per site. Things like (not a complete list)

- Photo sidebar
- YouTube embedding
- Chess board
- [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax)
- Some help pages
- The tour (if you have a proper one (I am looking at you, [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/about)))

The fields in the user profile are fixed and users can sync one profile to all other sites, so it better have all the fields in that case. There are no per-site variations. So that explains the why.

While you might at first sight assume that GitHub is dedicated to programming, there is no restriction on what you can version control, do its life-cycle management and feed other than software consumers. [GitHub Pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub#GitHub_Pages) springs to mind, but certainly others exist.

It will probably be more confusing if the GitHub link was removed / hidden from the user profile on sites that you/we deem "not programming related" (aka NPR).

Comment: Re *"...mother ship"*: Careful now...